# How to set the seek time to jwplayer

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer7

I am using the seek(second) method to  skip the some video.

```
 function playTheVideo(seekTimeInSec){

    var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
        playerInstance.setup({
        file: "https://storage.googleapis.com/webinar_video/abcdedbv.mp4"
        });
        playerInstance.seek(seekTimeInSec);
}
```

calling  by

```
  playTheVideo(500);
```

but  player is playing video from the starting **not  forwarding video with 500 second**. I want to play my video after the  500 second from the  starting 0:00.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the player is fully ready before trying to perform a seek action. Try including your seek call inside the 'ready' event listener:

```
function playTheVideo(seekTimeInSec){

    var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
    playerInstance.setup({
        file: "https://storage.googleapis.com/webinar_video/abcdedbv.mp4"
    });
    playerInstance.on('ready', function(){
        playerInstance.seek(seekTimeInSec);
    });        
}
```